# crontab.service file not found despite installed and configured crontab

Tags: cron, services, manjaro

I want to set up crontab every minute on Manjaro, so I've put [some script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398044) every minute with:

```
$ crontab -e
* * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh
crontab: installing new crontab
```

Then I see it is installed

```
$ crontab -l
```

but I see it is not working, so I try to restart:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart crontab 
Failed to restart crontab.service: Unit crontab.service not found.

$ sudo systemctl restart cron.service
Failed to restart cron.service: Unit cron.service not found.

$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i cron    # No output
```

Then I've noticed that no file `cron.service` was found on my computer, so I've found `cron.service` on different computer (with Mint):

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/cron.service
[Unit]
Description=Regular background program processing daemon
Documentation=man:cron(8)

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/cron
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS
IgnoreSIGPIPE=false
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So maybe I can copy those files with all dependencies from the computer:

```
scp mint:/lib/systemd/system/cron.service /lib/systemd/system/
scp mint:/etc/default/cron /etc/default/
scp mint:/usr/sbin/cron /usr/sbin/
```

but I'm not sure if it is good solution?

I know that there are alternatives, especially [dedicated timers for Arch distributions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers), but I prefer portable between systems solution. Is it possible to use normally cron on Manjaro 19.02?

Comment: @roaima: I've answered You after the "edit" section in my euestion

Comment: I don't know why you have a `cron` client but no daemon. Isn't `cronie` the standard one for Arch and Manjaro - should you install that?

Comment: @roaima: Maybe it is because it is adition for RaspberryPi 4. Probably Manjaro made this different than normal distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution on [Manjaro's polish forum](https://manjaro.pl/forum/topic/gdzie-jest-cron/). Instead of cron we should install `cronie`:

```
sudo pacman -S cronie
sudo systemctl enable cronie.service
sudo systemctl start cronie.service
```

Then we can configure like normal crontab.